# How to update Url used by UnityWebRequest to InputField?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, input-field, unitywebrequest

I want the user to be able to change the ID of the link, which is why I used InputField to get their input. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out, how to make it work smoothly with a Coroutine.
When I try to update the link, it just ends in an endless loop like with the implementation below. When I don't update the link the Coroutine seems to start without getting the input and gets stuck.
I would really appreciate any help.

```cs
public class CSVDownloader : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static string googleSheetDocID;
    public static string url;
    public InputField InputField;
    public static string csvDownloaded;
    
    public static CSVParametersData downloadedData;

    public void Start()
    {
        googleSheetDocID = InputField.text;
        Debug.Log(googleSheetDocID);
        StartCoroutine(DownloadData());
        
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        googleSheetDocID = InputField.text;
        Debug.Log(googleSheetDocID);
    }

    public static IEnumerator DownloadData()
    {
        Debug.Log(("In Coroutine"));
        //url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ufpl1MsxXU2bk0Kt5YT_BkM1uI2WMLxr/export? format=csv";
        url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + googleSheetDocID + "/export?format=csv";
        Debug.Log(url);

        UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        Debug.Log("Starting Download...");
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        Debug.Log("Webrequestsend");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `StartCoroutine` in `Start`. When you get the text value in `Update`, you are not doing anything. What are you expecting to happen here? How can there be an endless loop when you are not using a single loop or recursive routine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How about doing it in a few more steps?

In the code presented above, the user interaction ends with keyboard input. So trying to do everything in real time is a problem.

If the only user interaction is the keyboard, it is **complex and difficult** to achieve the desired task.

If it were me, I would improve the code to make it easier to achieve what you want by proceeding like this:

**Add that script to your Button GameObject**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CsvDownloader : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField] private InputField inputField;
  
  private Button changeUrlButotn;
  private string googleSheetDocID;
  private string url;

  private void Awake()
  {
    changeUrlButotn = GetComponent<Button>();
    changeUrlButotn.onClick.AddListener(OnChangeUrl);
  }

  private void OnChangeUrl()
  {
    googleSheetDocID = inputField.text;
    StartCoroutine(DownloadData());
  }

  private IEnumerator DownloadData()
  {
    url = Path.Combine(
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d",
      googleSheetDocID,
      "export?format=csv");

    Debug.Log(url);

    using var unityWebRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    unityWebRequest.SendWebRequest();

    while (!unityWebRequest.isDone)
    {
      yield return null;
      
      // Things to process in units of frames
      // when unityWebRequest has not finished downloading ex) progress
      // ...
    }

    Debug.Log("Success DownloadData()");
  }
}
```

Separate the part that inputs the **InputField** with the keyboard and the part that updates the `googleSheetDocID`.

---

FYI, as *@Max Play* said, infinite loop doesn't happen.

Hope your problem is solved :)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help! I am having trouble with this sadly. I keep getting a NullReferenceException in the line with AddListener, but I can't figure out why. What I have to do is, assign the script to an object in the scene, add a button and then on the button, OnClick() I need to select the Awake Function right? I also changed everything because I couldn't figure out the problem. Am I supposed to change something?

Comment: @tryingtoflow Did you assign GameObject for `inputfield` in Inspector?

Comment: yes, it's working even though I am getting a NullReferenceException for the //changeUrlButton.onClick.AddListener(OnChangeUrl)// line. I will ask a tutor tho thank you very much!

Comment: @tryingtoflow I have uploaded the Unity package [here](https://github.com/Goisak100/URL_Test). Would you like to create a new project and check it out? There is no more help I can give...

Comment: thank you so much! I figured it out, I was using a separate GameObject to act as a Scriptholder which I guess just didn't work out. Thank you for your time and effort!